# DynamoDBAutoGeneratedTimestamp CREATE strategy is always updating?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to use the DynamoDBAutoGeneratedTimestamp annotation for generating timestamps for when my records are last updated and when they are created. The annotation currently has 2 strategies, ALWAYS and CREATE.

My **initial** understanding was that the ALWAYS strategy should update the timestamp every time the record is changed, and the CREATE strategy should set the timestamp only when the record is created. The ALWAYS strategy appears to be working just fine in updating the timestamp each time the record changes; however, the CREATE strategy appears to be behaving exactly the same as the ALWAYS strategy (meaning the timestamp updates each time the record changes).

It is now my understanding that the CREATE strategy doesn't do that, and instead tells the record to generate a timestamp if you're going to write it to the database and the value of the field in the record to be written is null.

This causes the field with the CREATE strategy to always be updated if the record itself is ever updated.

So, are there any easy solutions to this? I could set it myself, of course, but I was wondering if there is some sort of option or config that is not known to me that would address this issue?

Example code:

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "Foo")
public class Foo {
    @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedTimestamp(strategy = DynamoDBAutoGenerateStrategy.CREATE)
    private Date createdAt;

    @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedTimestamp(strategy = DynamoDBAutoGenerateStrategy.ALWAYS)
    private Date updatedAt;
}
```

Comment: Are you performing PutItem or UpdateItem?

Comment: @RichardDunn Mostly UpdateItem, but I would like to move forward assuming I am doing both.